# JSP Json ArrayList to JavaScript list

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

I have the following JSON data retreived from a Java servlet. I would like to add each latitude and longitude (bottom two variables) to a javascript list so I can later plot them to a map. here is the code:

```
    <c:set var="object" value="${json}" />

Minlon : <c:out value="${object.minlon}"/><br>
MinLat : <c:out value="${object.minlat}"/><br>
Maxlon : <c:out value="${object.maxlon}"/><br>
MaxLat : <c:out value="${object.maxlon}"/><br><br>

Stops : <br>
<c:forEach items="${object.stops}" var="stop">
    Name : <c:out value="${stop.name}"/><br>

    Longitude : <c:out value="${stop.longitude}"/><br>
    Latitude:  <c:out value="${stop.latitude}"/><br>

    <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

sample JSON:

```
{
    "minlon": -0.227758,
    "minlat": 51.407351,
    "maxlon": -0.027758,
    "maxlat": 51.607351,
    "searchlon": -0.127758,
    "searchlat": 51.507351,
    "page": 1,
    "rpp": 3,
    "total": 5939,
    "request_time": "2018-04-26T14:02:38+01:00",
    "stops": [
        {

            "longitude": -0.12673,
            "latitude": 51.50716
        },
        {

            "longitude": -0.12662,
            "latitude": 51.50728
        },
        {

            "longitude": -0.12741,
            "latitude": 51.50812
        }
    ]
}
```

could anyone tell me how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Post some sample json

Comment: added some mate!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the above sample is passed in as a string,

```
let stops = JSON.parse(sampleJson).stops
```

the above will give you a list of `stop` objects to work with.